# Mode where I can instantly change all same variables

Tags: java, eclipse

I have discovered a mode in `eclipse kepler`, where I can instantly change all same variables. When I am in this mode I get a box around the same variables and I can change one and instantly all others change.

I do not know how to enter this mode "by will", I just entered it "randomly". Therefore, I really appreciate your suggestions, how to enter this mode, because it is extremely useful to me!

PS.: I am using NO plugins, just a plain new eclipse installation with java!

Comment: place the cursor on the desired variable, then `Shift+Alt+R` for renaming. It's part of Refactoring set of tools you can see by pressing `Shift+Alt+T`, or going through the context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Highlight the name of the variable.
2. Right-click on the highlighted word.
3. Hover over "Refactor".
4. Choose "Rename..." from the new window which pops up.
5. Now you're able to type what the variable should be changed to.
6. Press enter and all instances of the variable will be changed.